# Is it possible to connect slots of a model object to the GUI in QT4 -Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

So I try to build a Model-View window using QTDesigner and C++.

For that reason I created a QOBject derived class as my model. It provides slots and signals to access it like: setFileName(QString) or fileNameChanged(QString).

I got a little into using signal drag and drop in QTDesigner and found it quite VA-Smalltalk-Like nice. After a while I was wondering if I could also connect my model to this. So is it possible to somehow introduce my model object into the Window/GUI and let QTDesigner connect signals and slots from the model object to the GUI.

In essence: Write for me:

```
connect( model, SIGNAL(fileNameChanged(QString)), ui->labelFn, SLOT(setText(QString)))
connect( ui-textEdit2, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), model, SLOT(setFileName(QString)))
```

Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

As jopa said, if you want to do it in the Designer, you need to make the Designer aware of your component, which is probably only worthwhile if it is something you will reuse often.  IMHO, the Designer is great for prototyping or creating an initial UI design, but not so good for long term maintenance.  Although, the Designer is very powerful, there are a number of options that aren't exposed through the interface.

I suggest looking into the Qt's auto-connect capabilities.  It attempts to make connection purely through a slot naming convention.  Read more [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections).  I've been itching to try this out, but we are only just getting into our Qt 4 conversion project and I haven't had a chance yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to introduce new types of objects into Designer is via a plugin, but that only works for widgets, via `QDesignerCustomWidgetCollectionInterface`. It would be nice if Designer allowed connections to other objects just like Apple’s Interface Builder allows, but it is not possible. For now, we are left connecting such signals in the form’s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I do never use the signals and slots editor of the Qt Creator, I do always use connect. It is much easier to have all signal and slot connections at one place, independent if they regard a library being used (readyRead() from QIODevice for example) or the GUI (indexChanged(int) for example).

This makes the code more readable + I have experienced much trouble with the signals and slots editor.